# InAppSettingsKit Tabbar, doesn't call settingsViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar, inappsettingskit

For a Iphone app I've tried to implement InAppSettingsKit (tabbar version). I succeded to integrate the library sample in my app but "settingsViewController" methods are not called.
This is my code:

.h

```
#import "InAppSettingsKit/IASKAppSettingsViewController.h"

@interface Settings : IASKAppSettingsViewController

@end
```

.m

```
#import "Settings.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>
#import "InAppSettingsKit/IASKSpecifier.h"
#import "InAppSettingsKit/IASKSettingsReader.h"
#import "CustomViewCell.h"

@interface Settings ()
- (void)settingDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification;

@end

@implementation Settings

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(settingDidChange:) name:kIASKAppSettingChanged object:nil];
    BOOL enabled = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AutoConnect"];
    self.hiddenKeys = enabled ? nil : [NSSet setWithObjects:@"AutoConnectLogin", @"AutoConnectPassword", nil];
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark IASKAppSettingsViewControllerDelegate protocol
- (void)settingsViewControllerDidEnd:(IASKAppSettingsViewController*)sender {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    // your code here to reconfigure the app for changed settings
}

// optional delegate method for handling mail sending result
- (void)settingsViewController:(id<IASKViewController>)settingsViewController mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error {

    if ( error != nil ) {
        // handle error here
    }

    if ( result == MFMailComposeResultSent ) {
        // your code here to handle this result
    }
    else if ( result == MFMailComposeResultCancelled ) {
        // ...
    }
    else if ( result == MFMailComposeResultSaved ) {
        // ...
    }
    else if ( result == MFMailComposeResultFailed ) {
        // ...
    }
}
- (CGFloat)settingsViewController:(id<IASKViewController>)settingsViewController
                        tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
        heightForHeaderForSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString* key = [settingsViewController.settingsReader keyForSection:section];
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"IASKLogo"]) {
        return [UIImage imageNamed:@"imager.png"].size.height + 25;
    } else if ([key isEqualToString:@"IASKCustomHeaderStyle"]) {
        return 55.f;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UIView *)settingsViewController:(id<IASKViewController>)settingsViewController
                         tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
           viewForHeaderForSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString* key = [settingsViewController.settingsReader keyForSection:section];
    if ([key isEqualToString:@"IASKLogo"]) {
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iconr.png"]];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        return imageView;
    } else if ([key isEqualToString:@"IASKCustomHeaderStyle"]) {
        UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
        label.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16.f];

        //figure out the title from settingsbundle
        label.text = [settingsViewController.settingsReader titleForSection:section];

        return label;
    }
    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView heightForSpecifier:(IASKSpecifier*)specifier {
    if ([specifier.key isEqualToString:@"customCell"]) {
        return 44*3;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForSpecifier:(IASKSpecifier*)specifier {
    CustomViewCell *cell = (CustomViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:specifier.key];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = (CustomViewCell*)[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomViewCell"
                                                               owner:self
                                                             options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.textView.text= [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:specifier.key] != nil ?
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:specifier.key] : [specifier defaultStringValue];
    cell.textView.delegate = self;
    [cell setNeedsLayout];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark kIASKAppSettingChanged notification
- (void)settingDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification {
    if ([notification.object isEqual:@"AutoConnect"]) {
        IASKAppSettingsViewController *activeController = self;
        BOOL enabled = (BOOL)[[notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"AutoConnect"] intValue];
        [activeController setHiddenKeys:enabled ? nil : [NSSet setWithObjects:@"AutoConnectLogin", @"AutoConnectPassword", nil] animated:YES];
    }
}

#pragma mark UITextViewDelegate (for CustomViewCell)
- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView {
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:textView.text forKey:@"customCell"];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kIASKAppSettingChanged object:@"customCell"];
}

#pragma mark -
- (void)settingsViewController:(IASKAppSettingsViewController*)sender buttonTappedForSpecifier:(IASKSpecifier*)specifier {
    if ([specifier.key isEqualToString:@"ButtonDemoAction1"]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Demo Action 1 called" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
    } else if ([specifier.key isEqualToString:@"ButtonDemoAction2"]) {
        NSString *newTitle = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:specifier.key] isEqualToString:@"Logout"] ? @"Login" : @"Logout";
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:newTitle forKey:specifier.key];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the `IASKSettingsDelegate` delegate?

Something like

```
self.settingsviewController.delegate = self;
```

in your `viewDidLoad`. Of course you need an IBOutlet property for `settingsViewController` that is connected in your XIB or Storyboard.

Comment: If you mean add IASKSettingsDelegate to .h ex: @interface Settings : IASKAppSettingsViewController <IASKSettingsDelegate> , I've tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ivan, to add a delegate, declaring protocol conformation in the .h file is not enough. See my updated answer. Signare, instead of bashing someone who tries to help, you're welcome to post your own answer!

Comment: I've added this code to .h : 
interface Settings : IASKAppSettingsViewController <IASKSettingsDelegate>{
    Settings *settingsViewController; }
property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet Settings *settingsViewController; I've added synthesize settingsViewController; and your code to .m but I can't connect IBOutlet in my Storyboard ("the table view controller" in Storyboard have custom class : settings)

Comment: Just noticed that you're using a subclass of `IASKAppSettingsViewController`. This is usually not required or useful. Normally, you just add the `<IASKSettingsDelegate>` protocol to the controller that manages IASK. In your case probably your root view controller. I recommend checking the sample app to see how everything is set up.

Comment: I followed this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291216/connect-iaskappsettingsview-to-tabbar-item) to implement only tabbar in the sample of library without the other two modes. Without the method of the question I can't figure out how to divide tabbar from everything else.